# SQL:How to select the first record from duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates

While Executing the below query to find the duplicate

```
select * from (
select a.* ,count (*) over (partition by a.ID) as tot
from HREMP a 
) tt
where tt.tot >1
```

**its returning 423 rows,**

I executed another query to find non duplicate record

```
  select * from (
select a.* ,count (*) over (partition by a.ID) as tot
from HREMP a 
) tt
where tt.tot =1
```

**Its returning 685 records**

> I found that there are 196 distinct records among the 423 duplicate
> Now, How to select the first record from duplicate records?

Comment: How to decide which is first record? By HREMP_ID?

Comment: yes .. @anonyXmous

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select distinct * 
from ( select a.*, count(*) over (partition by a.ID) as tot
       from HREMP a 
     ) tt
where tt.tot > 1
```

or

```
select * 
from ( select a.*
            , count(*)     over (partition by a.ID) as tot
            , row_number() over (partition by a.ID order by 1) as rn
       from HREMP a 
     ) tt
where tt.tot > 1 
and   tt.rn = 1
```

Comment: I was ready for the second query but the first one is a real surprise to me ,`distinct *`  ..  thanks for that..

Comment: you can give it the check if it answered your question

Comment: i tried twice but needs to wait 4 more minutes.. woaa

Comment: You don't need to use count(*) since row_number() will also assign a value of 1 in case ID is unique.

Comment: Using DISTINCT will slow down the execution performance. This can be avoided by using an analytical window function like row_number().

Comment: @anonyXmous No count kind of breaks `tt.tot > 1`.  The second does not have a `distinct`.